# Strategy browser game - Update tables on refresh

Tags: timer, browser-based-games

I am building a Travian clone for learning purposes using FastAPI for the backend. I want to update my current logged user tables whenever they are making a new request (such as loading a new page) unlike updating tables every x seconds.

Since I am using FastAPI, I found that a middleware could be a good option to update tables for every new HTTP request. However, there are a lot of tables that may be updated:

- Resources (always)
- Ingoing attacks
- Outgoing attacks
- Building / Upgrading buildings
- Building / Upgrading troops
  ...

1. What would be the best approach to update my tables for every new HTTP request? Updating every table may be a bit more time-consuming but probably easier to manage.
2. This is related to question 1, but since I chose to update my tables on every call, I must store somewhere a timestamp of a column `last_updated_timestamp` in order to calculate the new value. Should I create this column for every table that is re-calculated or should I hold a single `last_updated_timestamp` value for every table?

Comment: Does every single http request cause a change to every table, or are there some requests that are more specific? (eg. an "Attack" request might only need to update the attacks tables, not the building/upgrading tables). If you're trying to update your tables to account for stuff going on "in the background" unrelated to the current request, my advice would be: don't. Update that information lazily when it's needed, as shown [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/160697/39518) and [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/171700/39518).

Comment: Yep, I was trying to update your tables to account for stuff going on "in the background" unrelated to the current request but I will probably follow your suggestion

Comment: For your second link, it's interesting but where should I store this timestamp, in an isolated table?

Comment: That depends on what event the timestamp is recording. If it's the time the attack was initiated, it goes in the corresponding row for that attack in the attack table. If it's the time the build queue was updated, it goes in the corresponding row for that build order in the building table, etc.

Comment: If that got you on the right track, consider posting an Answer below describing your solution.

Comment: Thank you, I will in the next couple of days since it's become quite large and need a couple of hours to add all of those features https://github.com/Pierre-Alexandre35/travian/tree/main/travian/backend